# Is there an archive of photos shot by astronauts on the ISS?

Tags: iss, photography, astronaut-lifestyle

Many astronauts on the ISS take photos which get published. Is there a single archive that contains all of these? I've done several searches, but I only come across small collections e.g. on the Flickr page of individual astronauts.

Comment: images.nasa.gov ? The search interface sucks, so it's difficult to find what you want, but it seems all released NASA photos are there.

Comment: Try https://www.wikiarchives.space/index.php?/category/31

Comment: @Ohsin that's a really useful and well-stocked archive - you can search it by NASA photo #, which you can't do at images.nasa.gov. Consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Ohsin I second that your comment needs to be an answer. Great find!

Comment: @Ohsin thirding! I just searched that archive for "RPOP" and got a wealth of images (I think the official tool returned way more, but almost all of them were connector photos and this is mostly laptop screens which is what I want).  That's a good answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[images.nasa.gov](https://images.nasa.gov/) probably has the widest selection of publicly released imagery, but it's not a complete collection of every photo taken aboard the ISS.

[NASA Johnson's Flickr page](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasa2explore/albums/) has images broken down by ISS expedition. It's nowhere near the full volume of pictures taken, but it will have a collection of the best ones.

NASA's [Gateway to Astronaut Photography of Earth](https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/SearchPhotos/) has a collection of Crew Earth Observation (CEO) taken by crew members of all NASA missions. The search function is a little clunky.

Unfortunately for access to all photos taken, you need a NASA login to Imagery Online.

Comment: Yeah, I miss imagery online. That's where we'd get the funny / slightly awkward ones to decorate the hall for the crew return. Those usually didn't get released.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I printed out a particularly awkward one of Joe Acaba and Mark Vande Hei to sign when they came to MSFC for the crew debrief after their Expedition. We all had a good laugh about it.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from other official resources here is one manually curated archive with nearly 1.2 million public domain and CC-NC photos, documents and videos related to spaceflight.

Each entry has description, source and other metadata. They welcome contributions to the collection by registered users as well.

https://www.wikiarchives.space/

Comment: I can only accept one answer, but this was very useful too, so thank you.